# PHP: 2 tables - Maximum id2

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get all id with the max id2 value. 
I tried just to get the max id2 but then it will looks for the overall maximum value of id2 inside the table , but i want to get all maxiums of id.

So I got 2 tables - table news and table topics. 
Everytime I create a news there will automaticly create a topic. Now I want to show all news - and the current number of replies. So first step - topicid = id.

and every topic got id and id2.

id is the topic id 
and id2 is the reply id

so if i got topic (a) with 4 comments it would look like

```
(id(1),id2(1))
(id(1),id2(2))
(id(1),id2(3))
(id(1),id2(4))
```

now a new topic (b) with 6 comments

```
(id(2),id2(1))
(id(2),id2(2))
(id(2),id2(3))
(id(2),id2(4))
(id(2),id2(5))
(id(2),id2(6))
```

so i want to get ((id(1),id2(4)) and (id(2),id2(6)))

```
<?php
$news  = "SELECT  n.titel,n.datum,n.typ_news,n.news,n.verfasser,n.time,n.topicid,
t.id, t.id2 FROM news n  LEFT JOIN topics t ON  t.id = n.topicid 
ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 10 ";
$neuenews = mysql_query($news);
while ($dnews = mysql_fetch_array($neuenews))
{


echo "      <div style='text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;font-size: 24px;'>  "
          .$dnews['titel'].
          "a";
}
```

Ehm this was the solution :

```
 $dn1 = mysql_query('select c.id, c.name, c.description, c.position,c.bild,
 (select count(t.id) from topics as t where t.parent=c.id and t.id2=1) as topics, 
 (select count(t2.id) from topics as t2 where t2.parent=c.id and t2.id2!=1) as replies
  from categories as c group by c.id order by c.position asc');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT n.titel,n.datum,n.typ_news,n.news,n.verfasser,n.time,n.topicid, t.id, MAX(t.id2) AS id2
FROM news n 
     LEFT JOIN 
     topics t 
     ON  t.id = n.topicid 
GROUP BY n.topicid
ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I tried your solution (     $news  = "SELECT           n.titel,n.datum,n.typ_news,n.news,n.verfasser,n.time,n.topicid,t.id, t.id2 FROM news n  LEFT JOIN topics t ON  t.id = n.topicid  GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 10 ";)

but the result is  ((id(1),id2(1) and (id(2),id2(1)) so its not the maxium value of id2

Comment: You didn't copy paste my query right. Note MAX(t.id2) at the end of the first line in my query. The way you copy-pasted it has just t.id2 at the end.

Comment: Well i dont got a double news but i cant use

               .$dnews['id2'].

is it something new like   .$dnews['max(t.id2)'].    ??

Comment: See updated answer. Note `AS id2` part at the end of the first line. Now you can use it as `$dnews['id2']`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the specified/desired result from the `topics` table is accomplished by a query like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , MAX(t.id2) AS max_id2
  FROM topics t
 GROUP BY t.id
```

**OPTION 1**

To get that result joined to rows in `news`, you could use that query as an inline view in your query in place of the `topics` table. For example:

```
SELECT n.titel
     , n.datum
     , n.typ_news
     , n.news
     , n.verfasser
     , n.time
     , n.topicid
     , t.id
     , t.max_id2
  FROM news n 
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT m.id
              , MAX(m.id2) AS max_id2
           FROM topics m
          GROUP BY m.id
       ) t
    ON t.id = n.topicid
 ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

**OPTION 2**

If `id` is UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY) in `news` table, then you may be able to eliminate the inline view, do a join to `topics`, and do a `GROUP BY n.id`, something like this:

```
SELECT n.titel
     , n.datum
     , n.typ_news
     , n.news
     , n.verfasser
     , n.time
     , n.topicid
     , t.id
     , MAX(t.id2) AS max_id2
  FROM news n 
  LEFT
  JOIN topics t
    ON t.id = n.topicid 
 GROUP BY n.id
 ORDER BY n.id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score -1):

Not clear enough. what are the columns  id= 1 id2=1 etc.?    Two tables each with 2 columns?  No clue.

I'm thinking something on the order but No clue what you actually want.

```
SELECT `MAX(`id2`) as MAX,`id` FROM `News`  WHERE `id2` = `MAX`
```